# Issue with the Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having an issue with rails server while working on cloud 9. I was installing the gem 'jquery-ui-rails' and I needed to restart my server.

My friend and I share the workspace. The servers were running on my friends laptop so I decided to go to the tmp/pids/server.pids file and run the command `sudo kill -9 <PID>`, `<PID>` was replaced by the number in the file server.pid. It killed the servers perfectly. However, I get the following error after running the command `$ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT` in the terminal.

```
    kpauls@score_app:~/workspace (dev-messaging) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Error: Command '-b' not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

The most common rails commands are:
 generate    Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console     Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server      Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 dbconsole   Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
             (short-cut alias: "db")
 new         Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
             new application called MyApp in "./my_app"

In addition to those, there are:
 destroy      Undo code generated with "generate" (short-cut alias: "d")
 plugin new   Generates skeleton for developing a Rails plugin
 runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment (short-cut alias: "r")
```

I was also getting this error when I tried running the servers before I installed the 'jquery-ui-rails' gem or tried to kill any running servers.

I have done this before and I have had no problems with it. I really don't understand what the problem is. I tried looking for answers but couldn't find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

code in config/boot.rb

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
```

The error message after I ran the command.

```
kpauls@score_app:~/workspace (dev-messaging) $ rake rails:update:bin
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/ssh
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/joyent/compute.rb:3:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/joyent/compute.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/joyent.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/joyent.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog.rb:40:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
```

Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' 
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'ancestry',                '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

The terminal after I ran bundle update

bundle update

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Installing minitest 5.8.2 (was 5.7.0)
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7 (was 1.0.6)
Installing loofah 2.0.3 (was 2.0.2)
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.0
Installing rack 1.6.4 (was 1.6.1)
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.0
Installing globalid 0.3.6 (was 0.3.5)
Using activejob 4.2.0
Installing mime-types 2.6.2 (was 2.6.1)
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.0
Using activemodel 4.2.0
Installing arel 6.0.3 (was 6.0.0)
Using activerecord 4.2.0
Using ancestry 2.1.0
Using ansi 1.5.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.3.pre1
Installing sass 3.4.19 (was 3.4.14)
Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.0
Using will_paginate 3.0.7
Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
Using bundler 1.8.4
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Using slop 3.6.0
Using byebug 3.4.0
Using carrierwave 0.10.0
Using coderay 1.1.0
Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0 (was 1.9.1.1)
Installing execjs 2.6.0 (was 2.5.2)
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Installing excon 0.45.4 (was 0.45.3)
Using faker 1.4.2
Installing ffi 1.9.10 (was 1.9.8)
Using formatador 0.2.5
Installing fog-core 1.33.0 (was 1.30.0)
Installing multi_json 1.11.2 (was 1.11.0)
Using fog-json 1.0.2
Using inflecto 0.0.2
Installing fog-brightbox 0.9.0 (was 0.7.1)
Installing fog-softlayer 1.0.2 (was 0.4.6)
Using ipaddress 0.8.0
Using fog 1.23.0
Using foreigner 1.7.4
Installing rb-fsevent 0.9.6 (was 0.9.5)
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Installing listen 3.0.4 (was 2.10.0)
Using lumberjack 1.0.9
Using nenv 0.2.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Installing notiffany 0.0.8 (was 0.0.6)
Using method_source 0.8.2
Installing pry 0.10.3 (was 0.10.1)
Installing guard 2.13.0 (was 2.12.6)
Using guard-minitest 2.3.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.3
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
Installing sprockets 3.4.0 (was 3.2.0)
Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3 (was 2.3.1)
Using rails 4.2.0
Using mailboxer 0.13.0
Using mini_backtrace 0.1.3
Using subexec 0.2.3
Using mini_magick 3.8.0
Using ruby-progressbar 1.7.5
Using minitest-reporters 1.0.5
Using pg 0.17.1
Using puma 2.11.1
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4 (was 0.0.3)
Using rails_12factor 0.0.2
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.2
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using spring 1.1.3
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.3.0
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails 3.2.0
Using uglifier 2.5.3
Using web-console 2.0.0.beta3
Bundle updated!
```

Comment: Running `rake rails:update:bin` any help?

Comment: Also have you looked at `config/boot.rb` to check that the code in there is OK. Maybe something is set up incorrectly in the boot code that messes up the command line processing.

Comment: I ran the command, it says rake aborted!. Not sure why. I edited the question above with code in config/boot.rb file and the error message I get after I ran that command @Casper

Comment: Did you `bundle install` after you updated your `Gemfile`?

Comment: after I added the gem, I think I ran bundle update and Not bundle install. This updated all the gems in my Gemfile. I ran bundle install after. However, I don't think the bundle update cause any problems though. The app was running fine. Maybe one of the gems got updated and it interfered with the server gem. I'll include my Gemfile in the question above @Casper

Comment: Hi @kpaul any solution to this issue? I'm also facing the same thing.

Comment: yes, I did end up solving the problem. The problem was with the fog gem. The gem I was running was outdated. In the gem file, I had the version gem 'fog', '1.23.0'.  When I ran bundle update, It didn't update because i had set up as strictly 1.23.0. Now, I have the it as gem 'fog',                     '~> 1.36' which updates to the latest version but not major updates. This worked for me. Give it a try. If not, carrier wave could also be causing problems or some other gem