# Issue with rails server(WEBrick)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have posted this question before but I had no luck. I am posting it again with extra information that might help solve the problem.

I am having an issue with rails server while working on cloud 9. I was installing the gem 'jquery-ui-rails' and I needed to restart my server.

My friend and I share the workspace. The servers were running on my friends laptop so I decided to go to the tmp/pids/server.pids file and run the command `sudo kill -9 <PID>, <PID>` was replaced by the number in the file `server.pid.` It killed the servers perfectly. However, I get the following error after running the command $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT in the terminal.

```
kpauls@score_app:~/workspace (dev-messaging) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Error: Command '-b' not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

I have done this before and I have had no problems with it. I really don't understand what the problem is.

After I added the gem, I think I ran bundle update and Not bundle install. This updated all the gems in my Gemfile. I ran bundle install after. However, I don't think the bundle update cause any problems though. The app was running fine. Maybe one of the gems got updated and it interfered with the server gem.

I have included the terminal after I ran bundle update.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Installing minitest 5.8.2 (was 5.7.0)
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.7 (was 1.0.6)
Installing loofah 2.0.3 (was 2.0.2)
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.0
Installing rack 1.6.4 (was 1.6.1)
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.0
Installing globalid 0.3.6 (was 0.3.5)
Using activejob 4.2.0
Installing mime-types 2.6.2 (was 2.6.1)
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.0
Using activemodel 4.2.0
Installing arel 6.0.3 (was 6.0.0)
Using activerecord 4.2.0
Using ancestry 2.1.0
Using ansi 1.5.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.3.pre1
Installing sass 3.4.19 (was 3.4.14)
Using bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.0
Using will_paginate 3.0.7
Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.10
Using bundler 1.8.4
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using debugger-linecache 1.2.0
Using slop 3.6.0
Using byebug 3.4.0
Using carrierwave 0.10.0
Using coderay 1.1.0
Installing coffee-script-source 1.10.0 (was 1.9.1.1)
Installing execjs 2.6.0 (was 2.5.2)
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Installing excon 0.45.4 (was 0.45.3)
Using faker 1.4.2
Installing ffi 1.9.10 (was 1.9.8)
Using formatador 0.2.5
Installing fog-core 1.33.0 (was 1.30.0)
Installing multi_json 1.11.2 (was 1.11.0)
Using fog-json 1.0.2
Using inflecto 0.0.2
Installing fog-brightbox 0.9.0 (was 0.7.1)
Installing fog-softlayer 1.0.2 (was 0.4.6)
Using ipaddress 0.8.0
Using fog 1.23.0
Using foreigner 1.7.4
Installing rb-fsevent 0.9.6 (was 0.9.5)
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Installing listen 3.0.4 (was 2.10.0)
Using lumberjack 1.0.9
Using nenv 0.2.0
Using shellany 0.0.1
Installing notiffany 0.0.8 (was 0.0.6)
Using method_source 0.8.2
Installing pry 0.10.3 (was 0.10.1)
Installing guard 2.13.0 (was 2.12.6)
Using guard-minitest 2.3.1
Using jbuilder 2.2.3
Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
Installing sprockets 3.4.0 (was 3.2.0)
Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3 (was 2.3.1)
Using rails 4.2.0
Using mailboxer 0.13.0
Using mini_backtrace 0.1.3
Using subexec 0.2.3
Using mini_magick 3.8.0
Using ruby-progressbar 1.7.5
Using minitest-reporters 1.0.5
Using pg 0.17.1
Using puma 2.11.1
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4 (was 0.0.3)
Using rails_12factor 0.0.2
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.2
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using spring 1.1.3
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using turbolinks 2.3.0
Using twitter-bootstrap-rails 3.2.0
Using uglifier 2.5.3
Using web-console 2.0.0.beta3
Bundle updated!
```

config/boot.rb file

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
```

**Things I have tried**

I had posted this question earlier and I was given a few suggestions. First suggestion was to run the command `$ rake rails:update:bin`. This command didn't work. Another suggestion was to look in the `config/boot.rb` file to see if anything was incorrect. I included that file as well. I have never made changes to that file. So it must be good.

I tried looking for answers but couldn't find anything. I am reposting this question with the bundle update code in the terminal hoping it might help solve the problem. Any kind of direction or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, you should consider adding what you've tried to your original question. That way it's all under one roof.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with the Rails Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740502/issue-with-the-rails-server)

Comment: That's the question I posted earlier. I reposted the question with extra information to see if it could help solve the problem @JoeKennedy

Comment: I have searched the web for an answer but couldn't find any. People have had similar problem and a different solution has worked for each one. I am not sure how to debug the problem